# Out of index in NLP

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to import sentences and then select each word and compare them with a certain word (here, it is 'play')

The code is:

```py
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet 

mytext = "Hello Adam how are you? I hope everything is going well. Today is a good day, see you dude."

print(sent_tokenize(mytext))
y = sent_tokenize(mytext)
print(y[0])
x = word_tokenize(y[0])

print(x[0])
print(x[1])
print(x[2])
print(x[3])



for i in range (9):
    syn = wordnet.synsets(x[i])
    if syn:
        syn = syn[0]
    else:
        continue
    w1 = wordnet.synset('play.n.01')
    w2 = wordnet.synset(syn.name())
    print(w1.wup_similarity(w2))
```

But the code gets error after 3rd iteration with `'out of index'` error.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-202-75ef16a26fe4> in <module>()
     18 
     19 for i in range (9):
---> 20     syn = wordnet.synsets(x[i])
     21     if syn:
     22         syn = syn[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: when i = 3 the problem occurs

Comment: Always share the entire error message. What do you understand from the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through your `x` array, from the word tokens. There are not 9 items in the array, so when `i` tries to go above 3, it cannot find an indexed item in the list.

Use the length of array `x` as your range:

```py
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet 

mytext = "Hello Adam how are you? I hope everything is going well. Today is a good day, see you dude."

print(sent_tokenize(mytext))
y = sent_tokenize(mytext)
print(y[0])
x = word_tokenize(y[0])
print(x)

for i in range(len(x)):
    syn = wordnet.synsets(x[i])
    if syn:
        syn = syn[0]
    else:
        print('no')
        continue
    w1 = wordnet.synset('play.n.01')
    w2 = wordnet.synset(syn.name())
    print(w1.wup_similarity(w2))
```

**output**

```
['Hello Adam how are you?', 'I hope everything is going well.', 'Today is a good day, see you dude.']
Hello Adam how are you?
['Hello', 'Adam', 'how', 'are', 'you', '?']
0.42857142857142855
0.14285714285714285
no
0.2857142857142857
no
no
```

After reading the [docs](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html), I noticed your code here `w1 = wordnet.synset('play.n.01')` is doing Noun comparison. So `'no'` is being printed for non-nouns.